# Фиксация динамически созданной формы.

Tags: javascript

Есть вот такой javasript, он динамически добавляет поля при нажатии кнопки.

Как можно его зафиксировать, чтобы при обновлении или ошибке ввода данных, созданная им форма не исчезала?

```
z = 0;
function onlyDigit()    // Только цифры
{
    if((event.keyCode<48)||(event.keyCode>57))
        event.returnValue = false;
}

function addRow() // добавление поля
{
    z++;
    tbody = partrow.parentNode;
    tr = document.createElement("TR");
    tr.setAttribute("align", "center");

    tdnumber = document.createElement("TD");
    tdnumber.setAttribute("align", "right");
    tdnumber.setAttribute("class", "white1");

    tdnazv = document.createElement("TD");

    tdtyp = document.createElement("TD");
    tdtype = document.createElement("TD");

    tddlin = document.createElement("TD");
    tddlinna = document.createElement("TD");

    tdkom = document.createElement("TD");
    tdkoment = document.createElement("TD");

    tddelbut = document.createElement("TD");

    t = z+1;

    tdnumber.innerHTML = "Поле "+ t + "." + " Название:"; //Вывод нумерации и названия нижнего поля
    tdnazv.innerHTML = '<TEXTAREA cols="50%" Rows="1"  id="nazv['+z+']" Name="nazvan['+z+']" Maxlength="200"class="inputform"><?echo $masnazv['+z+'];?></TEXTAREA>'; 
    //Вывод поля формы "Названия"

    tdtyp.innerHTML="Тип:";//Вывод названия поля тип
    tdtype.innerHTML='<TD><select id="typ['+z+']" Name="type['+z+']"><option></option><option value="1">Числа</option><option value="2">Смешанные</option><option value="3">Текст</option></select></TD>';//Вывод выпадающего списка "Тип"

    tddlin.innerHTML="Длинна:"; //Вывод названия поля длинна
    tddlinna.innerHTML='<TEXTAREA cols="2%" Rows="1"  id="dlin['+z+']" Name="dlina['+z+']" Maxlength="200"class="inputform"></TEXTAREA>'; //Вывод поля формы "Длинна"

    tdkom.innerHTML="Коментарии:";//Вывод названия поля Коментарии
    tdkoment.innerHTML='<TD width="50"><TEXTAREA   Cols="30%"   Rows="2"  id="kom['+z+']" Name="koment['+z+']" Maxlength="100" class="inputform"></TEXTAREA></TD>';//Вывод поля формы "Коментарии"

    tddelbut.innerHTML='<BUTTON type="button" id="delbut'+z+'"Value="' + z + '" style="height:25px; font-size:10px; line-height:1;" onClick="delRow(this)">Удалить</BUTTON>'; //Вывод кнопки "Удалить"

    tr.appendChild(tdnumber);
    tr.appendChild(tdnazv); //вывод форм

    tr.appendChild(tdtyp);
    tr.appendChild(tdtype);

    tr.appendChild(tddlin);
    tr.appendChild(tddlinna);

    tr.appendChild(tdkom);
    tr.appendChild(tdkoment);

    tr.appendChild(tddelbut);

    tbody.appendChild(tr);
}

function delRow(xRow)   //удаление полей
{
    if(z == 0)
    {
        alert("Минимум одна строка!!!");
        return false;
    }
    idxrow = xRow.id;
    tbody = xRow.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
    for(i = parseInt(idxrow.substr(6)); i<z; i++) //parseInt преобразует первый аргумент в число по указанному основанию, а если это невозможно - возвращает NaN.
    {
        document.getElementById("nazv[" + i + "]").value = document.getElementById("nazv[" + (i + 1) + "]").value;
        document.getElementById("dlin[" + i + "]").value = document.getElementById("dlin[" + (i + 1) + "]").value;
        document.getElementById("typ[" + i + "]").value = document.getElementById("typ[" + (i + 1) + "]").value;
        document.getElementById("kom[" + i + "]").value = document.getElementById("kom[" + (i + 1) + "]").value;
    }
    tbody.removeChild(tbody.lastChild);
    z--;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**A.** Один из 4-х способ сохранения данных на клиентской стороне, поддерживаемых современными браузерами: Web Storage, Web SQL, IndexedDb и досутп к локальным файлам.

**B.** Записывать состояние формы в хэш адреса (после #), одновременно обновляя его же в адресе для отправки заполненной формы.